CronWorkflow in Argo
I am trying to create a simple CronWorkflow as mentioned in the examples of Argo. However I am landing with this error when trying to submit it via the web UI.
Error: Bad Request: spec.entrypoint is required
Workflow:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  timezone: "America/Los_Angeles"   # Default to local machine timezone
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 0
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"      # Default to "Allow"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 4     # Default 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 4         # Default 1
  suspend: false                    # Set to "true" to suspend scheduling
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: hello-world-with-time
    templates:
      - name: hello-world-with-time
        container:
          image: busybox
          command: [echo]
          args: [" hello world. Scheduled on: {{workflow.scheduledTime}}"]

Any idea on what it is? I also tried deleting workflowSpec and move everything one level up - then the UI doesnt complan, however I dont see the job getting triggered again as per Cron expression.

So figured this out!
You just need to submit it through CronWorkFLow url.
cron-workflows/namespace

